# How can we find database performance parameter for last 24 hours on MS sql server?

Tags: sql-query-store

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.object_id, d.database_id, OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'function name',   
    d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,  
    d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],  
    d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count  
FROM sys.dm_exec_function_stats AS d  
ORDER BY [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

*plz help me out to find the database performance parameters for a last day*

Answer (score 0):

`dm_exec_function_stats` has a property called `last_execution_time` so you can use that to filter your query.

```
SELECT TOP 10 d.object_id, d.database_id, OBJECT_NAME(object_id, database_id) 'function name',   
    d.cached_time, d.last_execution_time, d.total_elapsed_time,  
    d.total_elapsed_time/d.execution_count AS [avg_elapsed_time],  
    d.last_elapsed_time, d.execution_count  
FROM sys.dm_exec_function_stats AS d  
WHERE d.last_execution_time > DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
ORDER BY [total_worker_time] DESC;
```

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-function-stats-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

P.S. you forgot to define `total_worker_time`.